# how to search data from tableView in ipad using textfield

Tags: ios, search, tableview

I have ipad which have tableView display content i want that when user enters any data in search textfield then the matching records should disply in the tableView.

```
- (void)onSearchButtonClick 
 {   

 if (searchTextField.text == nil || searchTextField.text.length == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You must fill the text to search first!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}

  [searchTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Here is what normally displays in tableView

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {




   static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";

       CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView 

                                  d      equeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)  
      {


    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" 
                                                 owner:self options:nil];
    for(id oneObject in nib)
        if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


}


      appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

ObjectData*obj;


    obj=[appDelegate.detailArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



type=obj.contentType;

content_Type=obj.contentType;

content_Source=obj.contentSource;
    cell.text=Content_Source;


   return cell;
  }
```

I want that when search is click it should match the record and display in the tableView

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in the onSearchButtonClick method

```
  NSString *firstLetter = @"";
  NSInteger strlen=[textfield.text length];
  for (NSString *ABCValue in ABCArray)
 {
    if(ABCValue.length >= stringlen)
           firstLetter = [ABCValue substringToIndex:stringlen];
    if([textfield.text.uppercaseString isEqualToString:firstLetter.uppercaseString])
    { 
            [tableArray addObject:ABCValue]; //Store it in NSMutableArray
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: ABCArray is array in which it will search mean array showing table data

Comment: Yes, ABCArray is an array which is using in the numberofRowsInTableView method .

Comment: why we are using firstLetter empty

Comment: Before entering into the loop we are clearing the previously stored text  . In the loop it is filling with some words . There is no need to concentrate on that point . Just check whether you are getting data or not

Answer (score 0):

First of all instead populating your table data with appdelegate array you should use another mutable array, which will have the copy of appdelegate array in the starting.
Then in your method for click on search button you have to write the following code to display the results in table.

```
//Allocate a new array....
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

//The search query....
NSString strQuery=[textfield.text length];

//Go through all the array for populating the table data.....
for (ObjectData *obj in appDelegate.detailArray)
{
    //Check for the tye of the object.....
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[ObjectData class]])
    {
        //Now the contentSource of the object contains the search query then add the object to new array....
        if([obj.contentSource rangeOfString:strQuery options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [newArray addObject:obj];
        }
    }
}

//Dont forget to populate the table with new array.....
yourArrayForpopulatingData = [newArray mutableCopy];
//after completion reload the tableview....
[aTableView reloadData];
```